# Chrome for Android - keyboard options

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Edit: this is an HTML/CSS question for my web app.

I currently have a field like this:

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

On Chrome for Android, when users tap this they get a "Go" option on their keyboard which I presume is to submit the form.

I don't want that. I just want a "Done" button or something so they can go back and fill out the rest of the form.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this functionality used in your app it code helpful to you.

```
java file Code:-

edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxt);
@Override
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                // Creating uri to be opened
                // action perform  
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - but to clarify, I am talking about Chrome for Android; this being a web-app written in HTML5/CSS, not a native Java app.